# rewriting a trig expression

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

I would like to write the expression
$$
H(\omega)=(1+q)\omega+\omega(a^2b-\omega^2)\cos(\omega\tau)-a(1+b)\omega^2\sin(\omega\tau)
$$
in the form
$$
\alpha_1\sin(\omega\tau)+\alpha_2\cos(\omega\tau),
$$
where all the parameters are real. Is this feasible? My thoughts on the problem are as follows, and I may be wrong here. Take $0<\epsilon\ll 1$, and consider
$$
H_{\epsilon}(\omega)=(1+q)\omega [1+\epsilon\sin(\omega\tau)]+\omega(a^2b-\omega^2)\cos(\omega\tau)-a(1+b)\omega^2\sin(\omega\tau),
$$
where $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}H_{\epsilon}(\omega)=H(\omega)$. If we assume that $\sin(\omega\tau)\approx 1$, then clearly
$$
1+\epsilon\sin(\omega\tau)\approx (1+\epsilon)\sin(\omega\tau).
$$
This last line is valid only if $\tau\approx\frac{\pi}{2\omega},\frac{3\pi}{2\omega},\frac{5\pi}{2\omega},\cdots$. We thus arrive at the expression
$$
H_{\epsilon}(\omega)\approx\omega[(1+q)(1+\epsilon)-a(1+b)\omega]\sin(\omega\tau)+\omega(a^2b-\omega^2)\cos(\omega\tau)\approx H(\omega).
$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the $(1+q)\omega$ term makes this impossible

Comment: Per the last comment, you are dead in the water.